# Type conversion problem in a PowerShell function

Tags: powershell

I am very new to PowerShell scripting and was experimenting with `Function`. This is the code I wrote:

```
Function Add
{
   $sum = 0;
   for($i = 0; $i -le $args.length; ++$i)
   {
     [int] $num = $args[$i]
     $sum += $num
   }
   Write-Output "Sum is $sum"
}
```

And I tried to call using `Add 1,2,3`. However, when I execute I get the following error:

> Cannot convert the "System.Object[]"
>   value of type "System.Object[]" to
>   type "System.Int32".

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

There's a bg trap in Powershell: `,` is the array operator. Try this at the command line:

```
PS> 1,2,3
```

You'll see that it's an array:

```
PS> (1,2,3).gettype()
IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Object[]                                 System.Array
```

Try to call `Add` without commas:

```
PS> Add 1 2 3
Sum is 6
```

Don't forget everything is an object in Powershell. You are playing on top of .NET.

So you have two friends:

1. The `gettype()` method which gives you the type of an object
2. The `Get-Member` CmdLet which helps you on properties and methods of an object

`Get-member` has many parameters that can help.

Comment: Thanks..I am from C++ background and didn't think twice before calling function with parameter separated by `,`

Answer (score 5):

Casting is normally performed assign the type at the right hand side:

```
$num = [int] $args[$i]
```

Could be this your problem?

---

Second observation:

As @JPBlanc has observed, you are passing an array to your function, not three parameters. Use:

```
Add 1 2 3
```

and you will get it. Anyway, you don't need casting in this situation. May be in this:

```
Add "1" "2" "3"
```

---

Obviously you can keep calling your function like `Add 1,2,3`, but you need to change it as follows:

```
Function Add {
   args[0] | % {$sum=0}{$sum+=$_}{write-output "Sum is $sum"}
}
```

Comment: Look a bit more Empo @Naveen made a newby error he tried to call with an array as parameter in spite of passing parameters.

Comment: You'll still need "," when you call object methods with parameters. It's really a trap in powershell newby or coming from any langue.

Comment: Yes, that's true. You call object _methods_ with _arguments_ (if any), in the common way, with commas, as you'll do in C#. You call _cmdlets_ with _parameters_ without commas.